# Django count sub-objects with ntext on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django

I have a `Claim` object with `ClaimAttachment` with a simple foreign key.

I want to filter Claims that have more than x attachments. Normally, I would just do:
    Claim.objects.annotate(att_count=Count("attachments")).filter(att_count__gt=5)

Easy.
Except that Claim has several ntext fields and that results in:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator. (306) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

That is because Django is making an outer join between Claim and ClaimAttachment and is grouping on all fields from Claim. Several of those fields being ntext, they can't be grouped by.

I tried to work around the issue by doing a subquery myself:

```
att = ClaimAttachment.objects.filter(claim_id=OuterRef("id")).aggregate(count=Count("id"))
Claim.objects.annotate(att_count=Subquery(att)).filter(att_count__gt=5)
```

But the aggregate cannot be done on the OutRef query. I can move the Count to the `annotate(att_count=Count(Subquery(att)))` but I'm back to square one because it's trying to group by all fields again.

I know that this is not really Django's fault but rather another SQL Server annoyance but I don't control this data model, let alone the database server setup. How can I work around this limitation and get my attachment count ?

Comment: **Warning:** `NTEXT, TEXT` & `IMAGE` is deprecated.

Comment: Those data types have been deprecated for 15 years. You should have really updated to be using `nvarchar(MAX)`, `varchar(MAX)` and `varbinary(MAX)` but now.

Comment: Sadly, I don't control the schema. We are migrating from an older .NET application and rewriting module by module in Python and then migrating to Postgres.